# What is the name of this puzzle with two overlapping circular tracks of smaller objects (spheres in this case)?

Tags: puzzle-identification

I have an old, poorly constructed puzzle:[image]

I've seen a better version of this, but all the internet searches I've tried have yielded either artistic designs or metal puzzles of interlocking rings.

What is this [type] of puzzle called, and is there a recommended place to purchase such things?

(And yes, one of the black spheres is missing - hence wanting to buy a better quality one so I can try to solve it.(!!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [Hungarian Rings puzzle](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/cgi-bin/puzzle.cgi?pkey=1251), designed by Endre Pap in 1982. Your version seems to be the default version (which I have in [my personal collection](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=26889) as well, see picture below), although there are [loads of different versions shown in the TwistyPuzzles Museum](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/cgi-bin/pdb-search.cgi?act=sim&ckey=&phr=hungarian+rings).

[image]

The type of the puzzle is a *2D moving marbles* type of puzzle.

As for where to buy it, your best bet is probably eBay or another second hand webshop, since it's 38 years old.
I'll see if I can find some other places that might have newer reproductions and/or an easier-to-find/cheaper version, though. Will update later on.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. I specifically recall a version of disks sliding around two channels similarly linked, sold in gift shops and the like. The action on that other puzzle was super smooth and I'm looking for one with good action.

Comment: In the forum post you linked, the third picture had a puzzle on the lower right off the image with yellow sliding disks. The version I'm remembering had disks like that, although I could be mistaken - it's been years since I saw this.

Comment: @user3.1415927 Which link are you referring to, since I've linked a few times. :) If you mean my collection post, I assume you're talking about [this one](https://s18.postimg.cc/ew14zrgix/DSC_0596.jpg)? That one is a [Rashkey 2](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/cgi-bin/puzzle.cgi?pkey=1448), which is a different type of puzzle: [_intersecting circles_](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/cgi-bin/pdb-search.cgi?&act=adv&mec=221&off=0). They are in general more difficult to solve than intersecting rings with moving marbles tbh, although there are also easy ones. Loads of variety in difficulty/sizes/colors.

Comment: I was referring the loop with 20 yellow discs set in a gray backdrop including a rotating purple circle. I think it's near the one you referenced. The golovka (totally misspelled) in the twistypuzzles shop link you shared is distinctly closer to the one I'm looking for.

Comment: @user3.1415927 Ah, you meant the [Top-Spin](http://www.twistypuzzles.com/cgi-bin/puzzle.cgi?pkey=727). The topspin also turns very well. So if I understand correctly, you're looking for an intersecting rings puzzle (like the Hungarian Rings you have), but with round tiles instead of marbles?

Comment: Yes, 80%. It could be marbles or disks or slides or something else, but the version I have can lose pieces fairly easily, and it also snags fingers if one is not careful. I'm seeking something both more secure with the pieces (robust?), and more gentle on the fingers. The discs one I had seen before just seemed to fit the bill. I'm open to other specifics if it fits those hopes.

Comment: @user3.1415927 it looks like this is a correct answer to the question you posted.  I would encourage you to give it a checkmark.